# Code coverage for Swift 3.0 project in Gitlab CI

Tags: swift, cocoapods, gitlab-ci, xcode-workspace

I have an iOS project written by Swift 3.0 with CocoaPods. I've configured Gitlab CI for this project and it works perfectly. This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
- build
build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
  - rm -rf Pods;rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace;rm -rf MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace
  - pod install
  - xcodebuild clean -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject | xcpretty
  - xcodebuild test -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=10.2' | xcpretty -s
tags:
- ios
- lunchdot
```

I can't see code coverage for this project in my Gitlab repo. At the moment a coverage column for all my builds is empty. I tried to set *Test coverage parsing* in *CI/CD Pipelines* Gitlab settings, but it hadn't any effect because I don't know regex for Swift. Is it possible to set up code coverage for Swift project in Gitlab CI? How can I do this?

Comment: Not even a single comment ... :( I need the answer too.

Comment: Did you enable "gather code coverage" in the scheme? I did... but nevertheless no coverage

Comment: @OliverM Yes, I did, but it hasn't any effect. I'm using Xcode tool for code coverage analysis.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out ... you have to use external tool like slather or xcov to calculate code coverage percentage and then create a regex that parses the percentage from the command line tool. This will show the value in GitLab.

Comment: @OliverM Can you write it? I want to get the right answer for this question.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I got it working, dude. Check out the answer below.

Answer (score 13):

So, I tried a million ways to do it and the issue turned out to be *xcpretty*. After I removed it I started getting consistent results with my gitlab ci coverage data. If you still do not want to get tons of data you do not care about, you can use *-quiet* in your gitlab yams file. I will post it all though, so keep reading.

One still needs an external tool for coverage analysis - *xcov* seems to not be available anymore so I used *slather*. Worked like a charm.

These are the steps:

1) Get [*slather*](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather).

2) Get your .slather.yml file straightened out. Mine looks like the following (*YourApp is the name of your app obviously*):

```
# .slather.yml

coverage_service: cobertura_xml
xcodeproj: ./YourApp.xcodeproj
workspace: ./YourApp.xcworkspace
scheme: YourApp
source_directory: ./YourApp
output_directory: path/to/xml_report
ignore:
- "**/Pods/*"
- "thirdparty/*"
- "./Scripts/*"
- "**/3rdParty/*"
- "../**/Developer/*"
- "**/libraries/*"
- "Module-Core/*"
- "Module-Components/*"
- "**/AppUnitTests/*"
```

You can get the test output as html, xml, in codecov.io, etc, totally up to you. Check out the slather GitHub page to see the possible ways of doing that. But for the current issue, all we need is slather reporting in the command line so gitlab can pick it up. That is where properly setting up the gitlab yaml file comes in.

3) Set up the .gitlab-ci.yml file. Mine looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build

build_project_1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - xcodebuild clean -workspace YourApp.xcworkspace -scheme YourApp -quiet
    - xcodebuild test -workspace YourApp.xcworkspace -scheme YourApp -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=10.3.1' -enableCodeCoverage YES -quiet
  after_script:
    - slather coverage -s

  only:
    - master
```

4) Next step is to:

- Go to your **gitlab page/profile** or whatever you call it
- Go to **Settings** and then **Pipelines**

[image: Settings/Pipelines]

- Scroll down to **Test coverage parsing** and add this regex expression there: `\d+\%\s*$`

[image: Add your regex expression in the space provided and then save it]

And that is it. All you need to do is invoke a build.

Comment: The regex in text is not correct, use the regex in the picture or ```\d+(?:\.\d*)?\%$```

Comment: The regex with $ in the end are not working for me. I use `\d+(?:\.\d*)?\%`

Comment: This seems to be outdated, `GitLab 14.9.2-ee` does not have the option "Test coverage parsing" (or I can't find it, but it is also not mentioned in the docs)

Comment: @Daniel yes, they removed it: now you should set it up directly in pipeline: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#add-test-coverage-results-using-project-settings-removed

Answer (score 10):

Since Xcode 9.3 Apple provides `xccov`, so here is a solution using this, that does not rely on third party dependencies (and does not care if you use `xcpretty`, `-quiet` etc.)

## Overview of `xccovreport` and `xccov`

When your Scheme has test coverage enabled (or when you pass `-enableCodeCoverage YES` to `xcodebuild`), an `.xccovreport` file is created. It contains the coverage percentages that you can see in Xcode UI.

The file is located in:

(for Xcode 9)
`/Users/somename/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-airjvkmhmywlmehdusimolqklzri/Logs/Test/E387E6E7-0AE8-4424-AFBA-EF9FX71A7E46.xccovreport`

(for Xcode 10)
`/Users/somename/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-airjvkmhmywlmehdusimolqklzri/Logs/Test/Test-MyApp-2018.10.12_20-13-43-+0100.xcresult/action.xccovreport`

(unless you specify a different folder in `xcodebuild` via `-derivedDataPath`)

Note: In Xcode 10, the `.xccovreport` file location is printed out in console after test finishes, but Xcode 9 does not do this. In any case, relying on this is probably not a good idea, as it might be silenced (e.g. by `xcpretty`)

The file isn't a plain text and to view it you have to call:
`xcrun xccov view <path_to_xccovreport_file>`

Which will output the report.
(You can pass `--json` for JSON report)

## What we need to do

We want to be able to parse the file and print out the total percentage (so then GitLab can pick this up and use it in the dashboard).

There are a couple of challenges:
- Firstly we need to find out the file path of the `xccovreport` which contains random strings (in two places)
- Then we need to parse the file (using some regular expressions) and extract the total percentage.

## The script

Here's what I am using (any improvement suggestions welcome, as I am not a bash expert):

```
#!/bin/bash

#1

# Xcode 10
TEST_LOGS_DIR=`xcodebuild -project MyApp.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings | grep BUILD_DIR | head -1 | perl -pe 's/\s+BUILD_DIR = //' | perl -pe 's/\/Build\/Products/\/Logs\/Test/'`
TEST_RESULTS_DIR=`ls -t $TEST_LOGS_DIR | grep "xcresult" | head -1`
TEST_COV_REPORT_FILENAME=`ls "$TEST_LOGS_DIR/$TEST_RESULTS_DIR/1_Test" | grep "xccovreport"`
TEST_COV_REPORT_FULL_PATH="$TEST_LOGS_DIR/$TEST_RESULTS_DIR/1_Test/$TEST_COV_REPORT_FILENAME"


# Xcode 9
# TEST_LOGS_DIR=`xcodebuild -project MyApp.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings | grep BUILD_DIR | head -1 | perl -pe 's/\s+BUILD_DIR = //' | perl -pe 's/\/Build\/Products/\/Logs\/Test/'`
# TEST_COV_REPORT_FILENAME=`ls $TEST_LOGS_DIR | grep "xccovreport"`
# TEST_COV_REPORT_FULL_PATH="$TEST_LOGS_DIR/$TEST_COV_REPORT_FILENAME"


# More general recursive search. Perhaps less likely to fail on new Xcode versions. Relies on filepaths containing timestamps that sort alphabetically correctly in time
# TEST_LOGS_DIR=`xcodebuild -project MyApp.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings | grep BUILD_DIR | head -1 | perl -pe 's/\s+BUILD_DIR = //' | perl -pe 's/\/Build\/Products/\/Logs\/Test/'`
# TEST_COV_REPORT_FULL_PATH=`find $TEST_LOGS_DIR -name '*.xccovreport' | sort -r | head -1`


#2
TOTAL_XCTEST_COVERAGE=`xcrun xccov view $TEST_COV_REPORT_FULL_PATH | grep '.app' | head -1 | perl -pe 's/.+?(\d+\.\d+%).+/\1/'`

#3
echo "TOTAL_XCTEST_COVERAGE=$TOTAL_XCTEST_COVERAGE"
```

## What it does

`#1` - gets the `BUILD_DIR` and then manipulates the path to get to the `xccovreport` file. Comment / uncomment the block for your version of Xcode.

`#2` - We start with the full report as text. `grep '.app'` takes only the lines that contain `.app`. This is guaranteed to exist, because there is a line that reports the total coverage and contains `MyApp.app`. There will be multiple  matches, but the first match will always be the overall total codecov score. So we use `head -1` to take that first line of the `grep` result.

Now we have a line that looks like this:

```
MyApp.app                                      12.34% (8/65)
```

We use a perl regex to take only the “12.34%” part.

`#3` - We simply print out the result (together with the variable name to make it easier to locate later in GitLab CI)

## How to use

- Replace `MyApp.xcodeproj` with your correct value
- Make sure the correct logic is applied in step `#1` (Xcode 9 / Xcode 10 / Generalized recursive search)
- Save to a `printCodeCov.sh` file in the root of your project.
- Make the file executable `chmod +x printCodeCov.sh`
- In your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, add a line to the `script` that says `- ./printCodeCov.sh`
- In your GitLab Pipeline Settings, set the *Test coverage parsing* to `TOTAL_XCTEST_COVERAGE=(.+)%`

## Notes

- This does not use the `--json` format of `xccov`. For that version, see below.
- This solution might be fragile, because of multiple assumptions about folder locations and report format
- I use `perl` instead of `sed` because the latter was too difficult (BSD/GNU differences, regex limitations etc).

---

#### JSON version

If you'd rather use the `JSON` report (from `xccov`), then in the script you need something like this:

```
# Xcode 10
COV_NUMBER_FRACTION=`xcrun xccov view --json $TEST_COV_REPORT_FULL_PATH | perl -pe 's/.+?\.app.+?"lineCoverage":([^,]+).+/\1/'`

# Xcode 9
# COV_NUMBER_FRACTION=`xcrun xccov view --json $TEST_COV_REPORT_FULL_PATH | perl -pe 's/.+"targets"[^l]+lineCoverage":([^,]+),.+/\1/'`

COV_NUMBER_PERCENTAGE=`bc <<< $COV_NUMBER_FRACTION*100`
TOTAL_XCTEST_COVERAGE=`printf "%0.2f%%\n" $COV_NUMBER_PERCENTAGE`
```

Comment: I'm developing a CocoaPod. Since I'm not interested in the coverage of the example app, but only the developed pod itself, I had Xcode set up to only gather coverage data for the built framework. Whoever also uses that setup should use `grep '.framework'` under _#2_. Other than that it works great.